# Nestjs memory leak encounter in version 6.10.11

Tags: nestjs

I upgraded my nestjs project from v6.0.0 to v6.10.11, since then the service's memory consumption increase till it gets to the limit and then the service crashes.
I downgrade back to 6.0.0 and the memory issue stopped.

My docker run with node version 12.4.0 on AWS.

Did anyone encounter this problem?

Thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

The issue reproduced in the flowing flow:
I have an Auth service which is decorated with request scope (meaning it is created within each request), this service has a logger service injected to the constructor, the logger service is not scoped. 
as soon as I remove the injection of the logger service the leak vanishes.

- still, in 6.10.0 it didn't happen.

** Auth service should be scoped since I need the authentication token from the request's header. this token I used for other REST calls, is there any other option to do that?

Comment: Consider creating an issue on Github https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues

Comment: Have you tried the latest released version, which is version 6.10.14?

Comment: I upgraded to 6.10.14, this is not the issue, i think I come up to the flow in which this is reproduce, I will update my question with the relevant informaiton.